# How to convert linked list to circular linked list?

Tags: c++, list

This is my linked list constructor and insertion function:

```
template <class T>
   List<T>::List() {
   _first = nullptr;
}

template <class T>
bool List<T>::insert(const T& item, const int& position) {
Node* ptr = new Node();

// sets node data members
ptr->data = item;
ptr->next = nullptr;

if (position == 1) {
    ptr->next = _first;
    _first = ptr;
    return true;
}

// iterates through list until reached position passed into function
Node* predptr = _first;
for (int i = 0; i < position - 2; i++) {
    predptr = predptr->next;
}

// repoints pointer of previous node to it and its pointer to what previous pointer was pointing too
ptr->next = predptr->next;
predptr->next = ptr;
return true;
}
```

I tried this before but screwed my whole program up and got lost so I just reverted back to what I had working as a starting point.

In my notes it says to traverse the list do this:

```
(_first != 0) {
   ptr = first;
   do 
   {   // process ptr->data
       ptr = ptr->next; }
       while (ptr != _first);
}
```

but when I tried changing the code to add this, it just screwed everything up. If I could get pointed in the right direction, i'd appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: "It screwed everything up" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Where do you set the tail node to point back to the first node?  Without that it wont work

Comment: I havn't yet. right now the last node has a nullptr. Thats why I need help changing from a regular list into a circular linked list. Do I point to the head node (_first) or do I point to what the head node is pointing to? What is it supposed to look like in the code is what im asking for. I don't know  what to do. whenever I tried pointing it to the first node, my program crashes. That's why I said it screwed everything up.

Comment: If you have a problem with the "is screwed everything up" description, then just ignore that part. Just understand that I don't know exactly how to convert from a linked list to a circular linked list. What part do I change the next pointer to point to the first node? And how do I take this into account when im adding a new node and it happens to be the "last node" in the list?

Comment: Do you know how to obtain a pointer to the last node?

Comment: Is that what I should do? How can I use that to make a circular linked list?

Comment: Are you supposed to convert a regular linked list into a circular linked list, or are you supposed to convert your list class so that it works with circular linked lists only, where the linked lists are created as circular linked lists from the very start.? You also might want to consider using a pointer to last node instead of a pointer to first node. A list pointer would point to the last node (or null) of a list, and the last node would point to the first node, so within the list functions, you could have pointers to both the last and first nodes of the list.

Comment: nice tutorial about circular linked lists [here](http://pastebin.com/egDECvDi)

Comment: And just to be clear, are you trying to convert your linked list ***class*** to a circularly-linked list ***class***, or are you trying to take a linked list and modify the pointers so as to make it circular?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your code so it is not tested. But I think this would work. First to make clear, I use zero-based-indices.

For the first part:

**Tipp** You can pass position as copy because a reference to `int` has the same size as the `int` itself. For larger object though it would make sense.

I added a member `size` function which counts the number of elements. The two asserts are assuring that you do not pass a `position` which is greater than the number of elements in the list. The second one guarantees that the special case is correctly as it tests if `_first == nullptr` then `position` must be zero because no other element has been added before.

```
  // create the node
  Node* ptr = new Node();

  // just to make sure position is not out of bounds
  assert(position <= size);
  size++;

  // sets node data members
  ptr->data = item;

  // special case, list is empty
  if (_first == nullptr)
  {
    // position must be 0 if you insert for the first time
    assert(position == 0);

    ptr->next = ptr;
    _first = ptr;
    return true;
  }
```

Ok for the second part:

When you have already inserted one element you can loop over all elements. I used a *special* node which is pointing to `_first` and started the looping at position `-1` this should ensure you get the previous element to reassign the pointers accordingly.

```
  // create special-node pointing to first node
  Node* predptr = new Node();
  predptr->next = _first;
  for (int i = -1; i < position; ++i)
  {
    if (i == position - 1)
    {
      ptr->next = predptr->next;
      predptr->next = ptr;
    }
    predptr->next = predptr;
  }
  return true;
```

I hope that works for you.